# How to obtain data from UserControl to Form? C# WinForms and SQLite

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

I know that this question has been asked, but unfortunately most of the answers did not solve the problem. So hopefully someone can help me :)

So here is my problem.

I want to get this data from *StudentLedgerControl* (I encircled it with red). Then transfer this data to a form called *StudentLedgerWindow*.

Although before all of this, a button must be clicked to show the *StudentLedgerWindow*, which once showed, the transferred data will appear.

**StudentLedgerControl.cs**

```
public void LoadStudentLedger(SQLiteConnection conn)
{
        SQLiteCommand sqlite_cmd;

        sqlite_cmd = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM Student", conn);
        SQLiteDataReader read = sqlite_cmd.ExecuteReader();

        StudentFlowPanel.SuspendLayout();
        StudentFlowPanel.Controls.Clear();

        while (read.Read())
        {
            sc = new StudentControl();
            sc.StudentIDLabel.Text = "Student ID: " + read.GetInt32(0).ToString(); // id
            sc.StudentNameLabel.Text = read.GetString(1) + " " + read.GetString(2) + " " + read.GetString(3); // fullname
            sc.StudentSectionLabel.Text = "Section: " + read.GetString(4); // section  
            sc.StudentLevelLabel.Text = "Level: " + read.GetInt32(5).ToString(); // level
            StudentFlowPanel.Controls.Add(sc);
        }
        
        
        StudentFlowPanel.ResumeLayout();  
}
```

**StudentLedgerWindow (expected outcome)**
[image: Image2]

**Show Window Button Event and User Interface**

```
private void ViewLedgerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Once clicked, the data should show on StudentLedgerWindow
}
```

[image]

Thank You in Advance :)
P.S. I'm new here, so if there are any problems with my post pls tell me so that I can change it.

Comment: I'm afraid that pictures of code are not acceptable here, with one of the key reasons being: we can't debug images! Please provide your code as text in your question.

Comment: ok sure, my bad.

Comment: I'm sorry, what is your question exactly?

Comment: I want to obtain data from a usercontrol into a form.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it... idk probably...

All I did is create getters and setters (*kek, I should have tried this first*)

Then calling the getters and setters. (*if that makes sense, hopefully it does*)

**Old Code**

```
public void LoadStudentLedger(SQLiteConnection conn)
    {
        SQLiteCommand sqlite_cmd;

        sqlite_cmd = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM Student", conn);
        SQLiteDataReader read = sqlite_cmd.ExecuteReader();

        StudentFlowPanel.SuspendLayout();
        StudentFlowPanel.Controls.Clear();

        while (read.Read())
        {
            sc = new StudentControl();
            sc.StudentIDLabel.Text = "Student ID: " + read.GetInt32(0).ToString(); // id
            sc.StudentNameLabel.Text = read.GetString(1) + " " + read.GetString(2) + " " + read.GetString(3); // fullname
            sc.StudentSectionLabel.Text = "Section: " + read.GetString(4); // section  
            sc.StudentLevelLabel.Text = "Level: " + read.GetInt32(5).ToString(); // level

            StudentFlowPanel.Controls.Add(sc);
        }

        StudentFlowPanel.ResumeLayout();
    }
```

**New Code**

```
public void LoadStudentLedger(SQLiteConnection conn)
    {
        SQLiteCommand sqlite_cmd;

        sqlite_cmd = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM Student", conn);
        SQLiteDataReader read = sqlite_cmd.ExecuteReader();

        StudentFlowPanel.SuspendLayout();
        StudentFlowPanel.Controls.Clear();

        while (read.Read())
        {
            sc = new StudentControl();
            sc.StudentId = "Student ID: " + read.GetInt32(0).ToString(); // id
            sc.StudentName = read.GetString(1) + " " + read.GetString(2) + " " + read.GetString(3); // fullname
            sc.StudentSection = "Section: " + read.GetString(4); // section  
            sc.StudentLevel = "Level: " + read.GetInt32(5).ToString(); // level

            sc.StudentIDLabel.Text = "Student ID: " + read.GetInt32(0).ToString(); // id
            sc.StudentNameLabel.Text = read.GetString(1) + " " + read.GetString(2) + " " + read.GetString(3); // fullname
            sc.StudentSectionLabel.Text = "Section: " + read.GetString(4); // section  
            sc.StudentLevelLabel.Text = "Level: " + read.GetInt32(5).ToString(); // level

            StudentFlowPanel.Controls.Add(sc);
        }

        StudentFlowPanel.ResumeLayout();
    }
```

**Getters and Setters**

```
    public string _StudentName;
    public string _StudentSection;
    public string _StudentLevel;
    public string _StudentId;

    public string StudentName
    {
        get { return _StudentName; }
        set { _StudentName = value; }
    }
    public string StudentSection
    {
        get { return _StudentSection; }
        set { _StudentSection = value; }
    }
    public string StudentLevel
    {
        get { return _StudentLevel; }
        set { _StudentLevel = value; }
    }
    public string StudentId
    {
        get { return _StudentId; }
        set { _StudentId = value; }
    }
```

Thank You :)

And also if there are any code improvements I can do please let me know :)